# Chrome-based browsers not correctly rendering <span> with pre-wrap set

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Given the following bit of html...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

    /* Code blocks */
    div.code {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
      display: table;
    }

    /* comment */
    div.code span.comment {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="code">
12345678
    main()
    {
        int a;
        <span class="comment">// Comment a1</span>
        <span class="comment">// Comment a2</span>

        int b; <span class="comment">// Comment b1</span>
        <span class="comment">// Comment b2</span>

        int c; <span class="comment">// Comment c1</span>

        <span class="comment">// Comment c2</span>
    }
12345678
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I display this in Firefox, I get...

```
12345678
    main()
    {
        int a;
        // Comment a1
        // Comment a2

        int b; // Comment b1
        // Comment b2

        int c; // Comment c1

        // Comment c2
    }
12345678
```

...which is exactly what I would expect.

However, in MS Edge (and other Chrome-based browsers), I get this...

```
12345678
    main()
    {
        int a;
        // Comment a1// Comment a2

        int b; // Comment b1// Comment b2

        int c; // Comment c1// Comment c2
    }
12345678
```

As you can see, the 'pre-wrap' is not honoured between successive <span> elements, even when there is a blank line between them (as is the case between "Comment c1" and "Comment c2". If I delete the css definition for span "comment", the problem persists. If I embed a newline INSIDE but at the end of the  text then that IS honoured, but messes up Firefox, and I don't think that's a solution anyway.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug in Chrome? Or something else?

Comment: Chrome shows it exactly the same as FF, once I remove `display: table` from the container div. What is that supposed to be good for to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will works :
comment the css **/* display: table;*/**. this Will affect the output :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

    /* Code blocks */
    div.code {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
    /* display: table;*/
    }
    /* comment */
    div.code span.comment {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="code">
12345678
    main()
    {
        int a;
        <span class="comment">// Comment a1</span>
        <span class="comment">// Comment a2</span>

        int b; <span class="comment">// Comment b1</span>
        <span class="comment">// Comment b2</span>

        int c; <span class="comment">// Comment c1</span>

        <span class="comment">// Comment c2</span>
    }
12345678
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does indeed look like this is the issue. I can't remember why I set "display: table" in the first place; I must have done it for a reason. The real css/html is much more complicated than the example I posted so I need to check through carefully to see if removing this doesn't break anything else., but your suggestion would seem to address the core of the issue. Thanks again